# Python: Why do we use boolean values in functions to return print statement in our main program?

Tags: python, function, input, return, boolean

quick question since I was not able to find a sufficient answer online.

Following code snippet:

```
def Credentials (x, y):
    list = [("test", 1234), ("test2", 4567)]
    for list in list:
        if list[0] == userinput1 and list[1] == userinput2:
            print("success")
            return True
        else:
            print("error")
            return False

    userinput1 = str(input("provide username: "))
    userinput2 = int(input("provide PW: "))
    Credentials(userinput1, userinput2)
```

I do not fully understand why the boolean values True and False will return the print statements. I know that we use return statements to work with functions in our main program and that we could also define variables and return those. But why exactly does returning the booleans will give us the print outputs?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: They don't return the print, the print happens independently when they are executed.

Comment: You shouldn't call things `list`, since it's shadowing the existing `list` object in Python. Also, `for list in list:` is not good practice, since you're not distinguishing between what you're iterating on and the iterated items themselves. It should be something like `for list_item in test_list:`.

Comment: "I do not fully understand why the boolean values True and False will return the print statements." Let's just take a step back. First, `print` is *not a statement*, and you *cannot* return statements, you can only return a value (the result of an *expression*). So you seem to be misunderstanding something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: It does not

*In your function/in my function shown below*,

```py
def returnBools():
    (print)  print('Printed')
    (return) return True
print(returnBools())
```

The `print` function and the `return` statement are actually two different things. The print has nothing to do with the return, and the return statement does not in anyway trigger the print function.

Additionally, the way we call the function can effect the output

For example, printing the function `print(returnBools())` will display the returned value along with any print functions in our function

*output*

```
Printed
True
```

But say we did not print the function and only called it. `returnBools()`. The returned value will not be showed in this case and only the printed values will.

*output*

```
Printed
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I was just curious, because if I would omitted the return True and False lines, the consul would always show "success" as well as "error"

Comment: Yes, that will happen. One thing I forgot to mention was that, your return statement will also exit the function. So if you take away the return statements, the program will continue to iterate in your for loop. If you'd like to remove the return but also avoid printing out multiple statements, you can replace the `return` with a `break` which should exit the loop.

Comment: Also, I'm glad to hear this helped. Consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark below the down/up vote button. And if you appreciated the time I took to answer the question you can also up vote the answer. Best of Luck!